# Return object using with() in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, lumen

Currently I get data like so:

```
->with(['posts' => function ($query) {
            $query->active()->available()->limit(1)->with('user');
            }])
```

and it returns the user data as an array of objects which is expected. Because I am using a limit and will only ever need one result, I'd like to return it as a regular object, so instead of:

```
"data": value,
"posts": [
    {
      "data": value,
      "user": {
        "data": value
      }
    }
  ]
```

I'd like to return it as:

```
"data": value,
"post":
        {
          "data": value,
          "user": {
            "data": value
          }
        }
```

What's the best way to go about it?

Comment: Long shot here but try to replace `limit(1)` with `first()`

Comment: @FelippeDuarte Not a bad idea at all and was even suggested on other forms, but doing so seems to then not trigger the `->with('user')` part, and still returns `posts`as an array :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `hasOne` association on your model that defines the scope you'd like.

```
public function activePost()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Post::class)->active()->available();
]
```

Then call `with('activePost.user')` to load that single, active and available post with it's associated user.

Comment: Seems like an idea! Will this work even if there is a hasMany relationship already defined? I just ran into the error of first() literally returning just one result instead of one result for each parent object... any ideas?

Comment: Yes - they can live side-by-side, they would be totally independent of each other. You can't use `first()` inside of a `with()` scope query as someone suggest above because it is expecting a query back, not a model.

Comment: Would I need to write in a `first()` on the new association too?

Comment: Nope - because it's a `hasOne` Laravel knows you only want a single model. Give the code a run in your project and see how it goes for you.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your relationship is a `hasMany`, `hasManyThrough`, `belongsToMany`, `morphMany`, `morphedByMany` relationship (I think that's all of them), eager loading will always return an array since the primary use of the `with` method is for adding clauses to a relationship.

Quoted from best answer on the laracasts forums: https://www.laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/first-and-take-do-not-work-correctly-in-eager-load-laravel?page=0)

@Dwight's answer is the right approach.

Comment: ... and how is this an answer to the question?