# Selecting value in nested array in VueJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to select a value of an object in a nested array. Data being returned from the API looks like this

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "data":value,
      "posts":[
         {
            "data":value,
            "user":{
               "data":value
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "data":value,
      "posts":[
         {
            "data":value,
            "user":{
               "data":value
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

And my HTML looks like this (`items` represents what was received from API, fetched by an appropriate `method`)

```
<my-component v-for="item in items" :key="post.id">
 {{ item.posts[0].user.data }}
</my-component>
```

Page data

```
data: () => ({
        items: []
    }),
beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
    this.search(to.params.query)
    next()
},
methods: {
   search() {
      // search stuff then response recieved thanks to Axios
      this.items = response.data
    }
}
```

Component data

```
<template>
  <div class="card facebook-card">
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'my-component'
}
</script>
```

Returns an error because saying the value is null. I tried to console log the data in the output - it also returned null, but `item.posts[0]` returns as expected. What's going on here? How do I access the sub array properties?

Comment: Does your component wait for the data to be retrieved before rendering? If not, what does the original `data` look like?

Comment: @Phil Thanks for the heads up! The component renders everything fine such as `"post.data`, but `post.posts[0].data`  or anything from the nested `posts` doesn't work...

Comment: Your data still isn't valid JSON. You can't have two separate objects like that unless they were in an array

Comment: Also, the `key` binding should represent a unique / identifiable property on the iteration item.

Comment: @Phil this wasn't the point of the question. Rendering is fine, key is set, iterations work. My problem is in accessing a nested array. I just put key there as a placeholder since the actual code is much much longer and not relevant to the problem

Comment: I'm asking all these questions because [**it should work**](https://jsfiddle.net/nwj0jxqq/1/) and because you haven't provided enough information to debug anything

Comment: @Phil thanks for your patience with me! I've posted the full data that I have :)! With the full data the key actually becomes the isbn, so `post.isbn` when adapted to this example

Comment: I have not once asked you for the full data. What would be good to see is the component's `data` definition, ie the original `data` property for the component **before** it is populated with remote data

Comment: @Phil I think the real lesson here is no more coding at 4am :P I've finally understood and updated the question!

Comment: How and where are you assigning the remote data to your component? Something like `mounted() { fetch(...).then(r => r.json()).then(data => { this.posts = data }) }`?

Comment: @phil actually on `beforeRouteUpdate` since the url param changes to reflect the search query

Comment: I guess the main question is, are you simply assigning the retrieved data via `this.posts = ...`. Also, shouldn't you have `await this.search(...)`?

Comment: @Phil Heh actually that's how I'm assigning the retrieved data - was that one of the caveats? Seems to work without `await`, that was set right before `axios()`. If I remove `async/await` the problem with accessing the data in the nested array persists

Comment: I'd be looking very closely at the retrieved data in the browser's _Network_ console. Make absolutely sure the object property names are as you expect and that everything you assume to be an array is actually an array. Some APIs are bad that way

Comment: @Phil Just double checked, its generated by Laravel's Eloquent and Postman shows everything to look good! Side note - if I could just [return an object instead of that array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48410201/return-object-using-with-in-laravel-eloquent)

Comment: What does your component look like? I wouldn't typically use a component with `v-for` **and** content slots as the slot context is outside the component

Comment: @Phil it's purely presentational, literally a div with a class wrapping a slot

Comment: Yes, but the slot context is the parent (see https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Compilation-Scope). Have you tried without a component?

Comment: @Phil I just tried it, got `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.posts[0].data')`. Using `item.posts[0]` correctly shows the first post object... So no difference...

Comment: Again, not seeing any issues ~ https://jsfiddle.net/nwj0jxqq/2/. Though your `:key` should be `item.id`, **not** `post.id`

Comment: @Phil, I know, that's the strange part... I'll throw a fiddle together tomorrow to try and replicate the problem.

Comment: @Phil don't know what the heck happened, but a computer and server restart solved the issue! How strange...